# Proof that $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1+\frac1k)^k = \frac{n^n}{n!}$ for all $n \in \Bbb N \ge 2$

Tags: real-analysis, induction

I've tried to prove this for a while now, but I can't get it:

$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1+\frac1k)^k = \frac{n^n}{n!}$ for all $n \in \Bbb N \ge 2$

Solution:

$\prod_{k=1}^{(n+1)-1}(1+\frac1k)^k=\frac{(n+1)^{(n+1)}}{(n+1)!}$

$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\left(1+\frac1k\right)^k\right)= \frac{(n+1)^n\cdot(n+1)}{n!\cdot(n+1)}$

$\frac{n^n}{n!}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n= \frac{(n+1)^n}{n!}$

$n^n(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=(n+1)^n$

$(n+1)^n=(n+1)^n$

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: $a^nb^n=(ab)^n$. No need for induction.

Comment: **HINT:**

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac1k\right)^k=\left(\frac{2}{1}\right)^1\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^3\cdots \left(\frac{n-2}{n-3}\right)^{n-3}\left(\frac{n-1}{n-2}\right)^{n-2}\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}$$

Comment: Do you also need to hand in  Ana 1 at Bonn tomorrow? ..... (I found it useful that (n+1)^(n+1)/(n+1)! = (n+1)^n/n!)

Comment: Thanks @Aweygan after too many hours solving math I was blind for that simple solutions...

Comment: @seyfahni If somebody has given a solution you are happy with, don't edit the title to say (solved). Upvote the answer and hit the "check mark" button.

Comment: @seyfahni In addition to Alex Mathers' comment, you can also answer your own question and accept your answer or ask the people who commented to turn their comments into answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following telescopic product in disguise:
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right) = n \tag{1}$$
leads to
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k = \frac{n^n}{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{n-k}}=\frac{n^n}{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot 1}=\frac{n^n}{n!}.\tag{2}$$
In the opposite direction, we may notice that $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k = \frac{n^n}{n!}$ holds for $n=1$ and
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k/\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k=\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}/\frac{n^n}{n!}.\tag{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

First, we can write out terms of the product as

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac1k\right)^k=\left(\frac{2}{1}\right)^1\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^3\cdots \left(\frac{n-2}{n-3}\right)^{}\left(\frac{n-1}{n-2}\right)^{n-2}\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}$$

Then, note that the cancellation of numerator terms leave only the last term $n^{n-1}$, while partial cancellation of the denominator terms render the denominator $(1)\cdot (2)\cdot(3)\cdots (n-3)\cdot(n-2)\cdot(n-1)=(n-1)!$.

Putting it all together reveals

$$\begin{align}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac1k\right)^k&=\frac{n^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\\\\&=\frac{n^n}{n!}\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: @felixmarin Thank you my friend!